# How can I share a MockMvc session with HtmlUnit?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, htmlunit, spring-test, geb

I am using [Spring Test MVC HtmlUnit](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server-htmlunit) with Geb to drive functional tests for my Spring MVC application. I would like to check that some session variables are saved properly during an interaction. I tried creating a test controller to return those variables, but HtmlUnit and `mvc.perform()` are using different sessions. Is there a way to use a single shared session between them?

driver setup:

```
MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx)
    .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
    .build()

HtmlUnitDriver driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder.mockMvcSetup(mvc).javascriptEnabled(true).build()
```

test:

```
when:
    via ProtectedPage

then:
    // this uses session A
    at LoginPage

and:
    // this uses session B
    println mvc.perform(get('/test/sessionAttributes')).andReturn().response.contentAsString
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Summary

Can I ask why you are trying to do some of your work in MockMvc and some of it in HtmlUnit? It really isn't designed to be used this way. Instead, I would recommend interacting with HtmlUnit to consume the session (as your browser would) and verifying those results.

The reason this doesn't work is that `MockMvc.perform` works in isolation. The HtmlUnit integration bridges the `MockMvc.perform` invocations to ensure they work as you would expect in a browser (i.e. tracking sessions). However, the logic to bridge the the `MockMvc.perform` invocations is encapsulated.

## MockMvc Behavior

MockMvc requests work in isolation and will by default use a new session on every request. For example, the following two requests operate on distinct sessions:

```java
// this uses session A
mvc.perform(get("/test"))

// this uses session B
mvc.perform(get("/test"))
```

In order to reuse the session, you must obtain the session from the first `MockMvc.perform` invocation and set it on the second the `MockMvc.perform` invocation. For example:

```
MvcResult mvcResult = mvc
        .perform(get("/a"))
        .andReturn();

// reuse the previous session   
MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession) mvcResult
        .getRequest().getSession();
mvc.perform(get("/b").session(session));
```

The HtmlUnit support keeps track of the sessions in [MockMvcWebConnection](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/htmlunit/MockMvcWebConnection.java#L58) and sets the appropriate session (similar to what you saw above) based upon the JSESSIONID cookie.

In order for you to reuse the `HttpSession` from the HtmlUnit support in a `MockMvc` request, you would need access to the original session. However, this logic is encapsulated within the HtmlUnit support and thus you cannot access it.

## Workaround

I don't expect that we will expose the internals of the HtmlUnit integration. I also would not recommend mixing and matching `MockMvc` HtmlUnit integration with straight `MockMvc` usage. However, you can workaround the issue.

The first step is to create a `ResultHandler` that tracks the last session.

```java
public class SessionTracking implements ResultHandler {
    private MockHttpSession lastSession;

    @Override
    public void handle(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
        lastSession = (MockHttpSession) result.getRequest().getSession(false);
    }

    public MockHttpSession getLastSession() {
        return lastSession;
    }
}
```

The next step is to ensure you register `SessionTracking` with your `MockMvc` instance.

```java
SessionTracking sessions = new SessionTracking();

MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
        // ADD THIS
        .alwaysDo(sessions)
        .build();

HtmlUnitDriver driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder
    .mockMvcSetup(mvc)
    .build();
```

Now if you need to make a `MockMvc` request, you can access the previous session using the `SessionTracking` object.

```
when:
    via ProtectedPage

then:
    // this uses session A
    at LoginPage

and:
    // this uses session A
    println mvc.perform(get('/test/sessionAttributes').session(sessions.lastSession).andReturn().response.contentAsString
```

Comment: The reason for trying to do this was simply to get direct access to a REST API to check server-side state after certain browser interactions (in this particular case, dealing with security redirects and saved requests). My workaround was to route everything through a wrapper HTML template.

Comment: @chrylis Keep in mind that Spring Security's Testing support works quite well with the HtmlUnit support. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withmockuser This means you can use WithMockUser (and the equivalents) to run the request as a specific user. This might help so you can avoid security redirects/saved requests.

Comment: This is in relation to SEC-3115.

Comment: You can also `@Autowired MockHttpSession autowiredSession` and use it in mockmvc requests `mockMvc.perform(...).session(autowiredSession)`